# Get OneDrive details based on URL(https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtLQ0D1mu8SWcw7SxEL4olaQ3B8?e=NHs43v)

Tags: onedrive

Suggest me one API to retrieve items based on URL (just like if we give drive id it will retrieve all the details same like if we give URL it should retrun details what inside those folders )

```
private static final String URL_LIST_DRIVES = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives";
    private static final String URL_LIST_DRIVE_ITEMS = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/%s/root/children";
    private static final String URL_LIST_FOLDER_ITEMS = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/%s/items/%s/children";
    private static final String URL_ITEM_CONTENT = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/%s/items/%s/content";
```